# After a (validation) error occurs in the backend (Laravel Jetstream), how to return back to register page showing the error as status?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFUw3.png)

I have added phone number column in jetstream register and make it unique.

Therefore, there wont be same phone number in the user table.

I tried to test it with registering the same phone number, and the error came. So its working.

But how do I like return back to register page and put a status there instead of Laravel Error Page.

```
namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['accepted', 'required'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'phonenum' => $input['phonenum']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the registration code inside try/catch block.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen im not sure which part, because im pretty new to jetstream laravel.

Comment: Put your registration code snippet in the question description. So people can see and offer help.

Comment: you need make validation rule like this

Comment: 'unique:users,phonenum,' . $phone,

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen ive put my create user code there

Comment: @Gev99 i already make it unique, now when i register as same user, it would bring the sql error page. i just want it to redirect back to register page and state something like error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code snippet you've shared. The validator is validating other properties but not the phone number. So add the phone number field and it should redirect back with an error property. You will access the error property as you do with every other property.

```
        Validator::make($input, [
            'phonenum' => 'required,unique:users',
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
             ....
        ])->validate();
```